# Autodesk Forge Viewer getScreenshot methode

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Im trying to generate a Screenshot from my forge Viewer with an explicit width and height.
Im using this methode:

```
this.viewer.getScreenShot(
            this.width,
            this.height,
            img => this.createPDF(img));
    }
```

If my height value is the full canvas height I can calculate a width value to fit a certain aspect ratio like 1:2.
If I want to calculate my height value to match someting like 16:9 I always get the full canvas height no matter what my this.height value is and my screenshot width will change to a value to match the 16:9 aspect ratio. I dont know if Im missing something or doing sth wrong or this this a feature from the forge viewer implementation. With this behavior it is impossible for me to make a 16:9 screenshot just from my canvas and nothing more. My actual goal was to render a frame into my viewer canvas to see the aspect ratio and switch between multiple. I was able to render this frame based on ratio and clientToWorld coords but my screenshot just expands to the full height size. Maybe you guys know a solution for this problem.
Thx, JT

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to [crop](https://shpontex.github.io/cropme/) the image to a certain aspect ratio? Or stretch it to that?

What **getScreenShot**() does is like creating a **Viewer** with the given dimensions and taking a **snapshot** of that. So you are not restricted to the current **Viewer** dimensions but could even create a better quality image than what the user is currently seeing.
E.g. I can create a **1600x900px** png no matter what the **Viewer** size is.

If you do not pass in a **3rd parameter** for the **blob**, the generated image will just pop up in another browser tab. You can test things in the **Browser Console** on any site that is using the **Viewer** via [NOP_VIEWER](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/do-simple-viewer-api-tests-quickly) e.g. doing this:

```
NOP_VIEWER.getScreenShot(1600, 900);
```

Comment: Hey Adam, thank you very much for your help. I tried to play around with the NOP_viewer methode to figure out what exactly is my problem. On a 2D Viewer I can create different sized images but no matter which numbers I input for the second value, I always get the full height of my viewer with a changing with based on the relation.

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, then this should help: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/more-screenshots

Comment: Yea great! That is what I was looking for. Thx, JT